# How to get an array of the values of all properties of objects inside an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I want to get an array of the values of each object I have.

I have this:

```
const numDataPoints = [
    {
      x0: {x: 807, y: 625},
      x1: {x: 15, y: 20},
      x2: {x: 5, y: 20}
    },
    {
      x0: {x: 11, y: 6},
      x1: {x: 16, y: 21},
      x2: {x: 7, y: 22}
    }
  ];
```

I want this:

```
[
  [807, 625],
  [15, 20],
  [5, 20],
  [11, 6],
  [16, 21],
  [7, 22]
]
```

I tried this:

```
numDataPoints.map((array) => array.map(axis => [axis.x, axis.y]));
```

but it throws this error:

> Uncaught `TypeError`: `array.map` is not a function

Comment: You don't have an array of arrays, you can't use `array.map` here

Comment: so, then what can i do? or how can i edit my question?

Comment: Those aren’t arrays. Those are objects. It’s not clear what ordering you expect. Isn’t `[[[807, 625], [15, 20], [5, 20]], [[11, 6], [16, 21], [7, 22]]]` what you’d need here?

Comment: Just to be pedantic, you can't use map _a second time_ here: the first `numDataPoints.map` is fine.

Comment: Luca is correct. It looks like you have an array of objects of objects. You can `map` the outside array just fine, it's the inside object(s) where you'd likely need to loop through object keys rather than using array methods. Looping through object keys should be reasonably well documented here on SO as it's a commonly asked question.

Comment: i nead yo pass other function as prop each numbers like this [8, 5]

Comment: $array =  (array) $yourObject;

Comment: @Andrew That’s not JavaScript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Array.map` to transform each object into an array of two-element arrays and then reduce to flatten the result:

```js
const numDataPoints =  [{ x0: {x: 807, y: 625}, x1: {x: 15, y: 20},
            x2: {x: 5, y: 20} }, { x0: {x: 11, y: 6}, x1: {x: 16, y: 21}, x2: {x:7, y: 22} }];

let result = numDataPoints.map(
    item => Object.values(item).map(({x, y})=> [x, y]))
              .reduce((arr, current) => [...arr, ...current], []);

  console.log(result);
```

Comment: Switched from poland to dublin?

Comment: @Ashh yes, temporarily, still love Poland but have assignment here :)

Answer (score 7):

You can use `map` method with `Object.values` and spread syntax `...`.

```js
const data =  [{ x0: {x: 807, y: 625}, x1: {x: 15, y: 20}, x2: {x: 5, y: 20} }, { x0: {x: 11, y: 6}, x1: {x: 16, y: 21}, x2: {x:7, y: 22} }];

const result = [].concat(...data.map(Object.values)).map(Object.values)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use reduce for that - below will work for other data too as we don't hardcode any key's names here.

```js
const res = numDataPoints.reduce((a, b) => a.concat(Object.keys(b).map(e => Object.values(b[e]))), []);
console.log(res);
```

```html
<script>
const numDataPoints = [
    {
        x0: {
            x: 807,
            y: 625
        },
        x1: {
            x: 15,
            y: 20
        },
        x2: {
            x: 5,
            y: 20
        }
    }, {
        x0: {
            x: 11,
            y: 6
        },
        x1: {
            x: 16,
            y: 21
        },
        x2: {
            x: 7,
            y: 22
        }
    }
];
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don’t have arrays in your `numDataPoints` array, but regular objects, so you can’t use `map`.

What you need is [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values). Alternatively, to *guarantee the same order of the keys `x0`, `x1` and `x2`*, [destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) with `{x0, x1, x2}` and then use `[x0, x1, x2]`.

The structure of `numDataPoints` suggests, that you actually want an array of *two* arrays, each with *three* `[x, y]` points, rather than just six `[x, y]` points. If you still want to flatten these sub-arrays, use [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) or [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) (currently a Stage 3 candidate, likely to become part of the ECMAScript edition finalized in June 2019).

Here are all six possibilities:

```js
const numDataPoints = [
    {
      x0: {x: 807, y: 625},
      x1: {x: 15, y: 20},
      x2: {x: 5, y: 20}
    },
    {
      x0: {x: 11, y: 6},
      x1: {x: 16, y: 21},
      x2: {x: 7, y: 22}
    }
  ];

// Object.values, same structure
console.log(numDataPoints.map((obj) => Object.values(obj).map(({x, y}) => [x, y])));

// Object.values, flattened with concat
console.log([].concat(...numDataPoints.map((obj) => Object.values(obj).map(({x, y}) => [x, y]))));

// Object.values, flattened with flatMap
console.log(numDataPoints.flatMap((obj) => Object.values(obj).map(({x, y}) => [x, y])));

// Destructuring, same structure
console.log(numDataPoints.map(({x0, x1, x2}) => [x0, x1, x2].map(({x, y}) => [x, y])));

// Destructuring, flattened with concat
console.log([].concat(...numDataPoints.map(({x0, x1, x2}) => [x0, x1, x2].map(({x, y}) => [x, y]))));

// Destructuring, flattened with flatMap
console.log(numDataPoints.flatMap(({x0, x1, x2}) => [x0, x1, x2].map(({x, y}) => [x, y])));
```

Comment: first one nests in extra array

Comment: @charlietfl Exactly, the fourth one too. I’ve clarified that now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys` to iterate over the keys within the object, like so:

```js
let data = [{
  x0: {
    x: 807,
    y: 625
  },
  x1: {
    x: 15,
    y: 20
  },
  x2: {
    x: 5,
    y: 20
  }
}, {
  x0: {
    x: 11,
    y: 6
  },
  x1: {
    x: 16,
    y: 21
  },
  x2: {
    x: 7,
    y: 22
  }
}];

let result = data.map(obj => Object.keys(obj).map((key) => [obj[key].x, obj[key].y]));

console.log(result);
```

You may want to flatten the result, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

This is because what you get is an object, not an array. Although you could try (Es6) :

```
numDataPoints
.map(_ => {
  return Object.values(_)
  .map(({x, y}) => [x, y]);
}).reduce((acc, elem) => [...acc, ...elem], []);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `array` is an object, so you have to map the keys before using another `forEach`.

```
const numDataPoints =  [{ x0: {x: 807, y: 625}, x1: {x: 15, y: 20},x2: {x: 5, y: 20} }, { x0: {x: 11, y: 6}, x1: {x: 16, y: 21}, x2: {x:7, y: 22} }];
var foo = []
numDataPoints.forEach((points) => 
    Object.keys(points).forEach(point => 
        foo.push( [points[point].x, points[point].y] )
    )
);
console.log(foo)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few different ways to get two different results (original nesting structure or flat structure) - also notice the sorting which could be a use-case for you - dictionary keys are sorted in the way they are declared (not alphanumerically):

```js
const numDataPoints =  [{ x0: {x: 807, y: 625}, x1: {x: 15, y: 20},
x2: {x: 5, y: 20} }, { x0: {x: 11, y: 6}, x1: {x: 16, y: 21}, x2: {x:7, y: 22} }];

// In case you need them sorted and in the original nesting:
console.log(
  numDataPoints
    .map(d => Object.keys(d).sort().map(k => [d[k].x, d[k].y]))
);

// In case you need them sorted and flattened:
console.log(
  numDataPoints
    .map(d => Object.keys(d).sort().map(k => [d[k].x, d[k].y]))
    .reduce((a,v) => { v.forEach(value => a.push(value)); return a; }, [])
);

// In case you don't need them sorted and in the original nesting:
console.log(
  numDataPoints
    .map(d => Object.keys(d).map(k => [d[k].x, d[k].y]))
);

// In case you don't need them sorted and flattened:
console.log(
  numDataPoints
    .map(d => Object.keys(d).map(k => [d[k].x, d[k].y]))
    .reduce((a,v) => { v.forEach(value => a.push(value)); return a; }, [])
);
```